# Issue with creating a simple heatmap from a frequency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, frequency

I'm trying to create a heatmap from the following matrix (bnc) :

[image]

Which would look basically like this (here it's another frequency matrix) :

[image]

I'm at the very first stage where I'm trying to create the heatmap, and have not yet figured out details about the colour scale and the blacking out of NA values.

When I run the heatmap function :

```
heatmap(bnc)
```

I get the following error :

```
Error in hclustfun(distfun(if (symm) x else t(x))) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in call to external function (argument 10)
```

Could someone help me figure out what's wrong here?

Best

Cameron

EDIT : here is the dput() of my dataframe:

```
structure(c(NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, NA, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
6, 3, 0, 0, NA, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 0, 1, NA, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(14L, 14L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("WILL_", "WOULD_", "MAY_", "MIGHT_", "CAN_", "COULD_", 
    "SHALL_", "SHOULD_", "MUST_", "OUGHT TO_", "USED TO_", "HAVE TO_", 
    "GOING TO_", "BE ABLE TO_"), c("_WILL", "_WOULD", "_MAY", 
    "_MIGHT", "_CAN", "_COULD", "_SHALL", "_SHOULD", "_MUST", 
    "_OUGHT TO", "_USED TO", "_HAVE TO", "_GOING TO", "_BE ABLE TO"
    )))
```

PS: I would like my heatmap to show the columns which are entirely made of NA values.

Comment: Hi @Cameron, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you share your data by copy-pasting the output `dput(bnc)` to your question? An image is not a useful way to share your data. That said, I think the error might have to do with the columns that consist of entirely NAs. You might try to remove those columns and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that! Is there a way to circumvent removing the NAs? Basically, I'd like the NAs to show up in the heatmap, as black tiles like in the examples. Even when the column is made entirely of NAs.

Comment: Just realised I put a wrong dput in my question, I have just re-edited it.

Comment: You  can use `heatmap(bnc, symm = T)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `ggplot2`

```
reshape2::melt(df, value.name = "Freq") %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(is.na(Freq), "NA", as.character(Freq))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Freq), color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", na.value = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, thanks !

What kind of commands do you think I should use to 
-flip the matrix and move the labels from left hand side and bottom respectively to top and left hand side?
-Hide the characters "0" and "NA" from the heatmap?

Comment: Change to `ifelse(is.na(Freq) | Freq == 0, "", as.character(Freq))`,  `aes(Var2, Var1)`, add `position = "top"` to  `scale_x_discrete` and put `hjust = 0`